# Нужна ли запятая перед причастным оборотом?

Tags: запятые, причастия, причастный-оборот

**"Он оборачивался на всех остальных (?) сзади идущих".**

Объясните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна: *Он оборачивался на всех остальных, **сзади идущих.***

**Пояснение**

1. В данном случае слово ***остальные*** используется в значении **существительного**. Причастный оборот обособляется в позиции **после** определяемого слова.
2. Наречие ***сзади*** препятствует слитному прочтению речевого оборота. Сравнить: *Он оборачивался **на остальных идущих**.*

Большой толковый словарь русского языка

**ОСТАЛЬНОЙ,** -ая, -ое. Оставшийся или не вошедший в число кого-, чего-л.; прочий. О-ые книги принесу завтра. О-ое время проведём в горах. О-ые сотрудники на конференции. **Остальные, -ых; мн.** Остальным придётся подождать. Вы останьтесь. О. свободны. Остальное, -ого; ср. О. расскажу при встрече. О. возьмёшь завтра